# Using Python environments and interpreters in PyCharm

Tags: python, metatrader5

I'm new to Python language and a little bit messed up with environments, interpreters, etc.

The problem is that I can't get working MetaTrader5 package installed through pip.

When I use the following code in Spyder or PyCharm IDEs:

```
from MetaTrader5 import *
MT5Initialize()
```

I receive

> name 'MT5Initialize' is not defined.

But the same code used in Python Console through PyCharm or IDLE returns:

> True

And this is what I'm expecting to see.

I have Anaconda and Python.org environments installed, ver. 3.7. Changing interpreters in PyCharm's project doesn't help.

Could you help me with any suggestion?

Comment: What platform/OS are you working on?

Comment: Can you clarify what "I receive" means? Do you mean that your editor inspections flag it as an error?
There is [a lot of documentation on PyCharm's website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) for how you can point it to the interpreter you are using. If you are not sure which interpreter you are using then it may be worth reading more about interpreters and virtual environments before attempting to set it up.

Comment: @normanius I'm working on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter SP1 x64

Comment: @Geekfish Yes, I mean that my editor flags it as an error. There is so much information about interpreters and virtual environments that I can't find quickly the exact reason. It would be great If you could point me somewhere written in a simple language. As I already tried to install package in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the MetaTrade5 package installed, try adding it to the project interpreter (In PyCharm File --> Settings --> Project: yourprojectname --> Project interpreter).

PyCharm has it's own environment for every project, so you also need it to add it to project them self.

Comment: It looks strange. When I install a package in a project interpreter window, it says me that a package has been successfully installed, but I still don't see it in the list of installed packages.

Comment: @Sergey Ok, that looks strange and you have an interpreter for your project selected at the top?

Comment: Yes, I have chosen "Python 3.7 C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" at the top of the dialog window.

Comment: @Sergey Ok then I also do not really know what the problem is. You can try reinstall everthing python related or just try to run your programm with the standard python IDLE and if then there are some packages missing, try to install them with pip install.

Comment: I reinstalled all the packages and PyCharm. Now I see MetaTrader5 in a list of packages in project settings but still receive the same error "name 'MT5Initialize' is not defined".

Comment: @Sergey And you also get same error when you start your programm with the command line?

Comment: Don't know why but it works through Python console.

Comment: @Sergey Sorry, but then I can't help you there anymore.